# Understanding "JNI Critical Lock held " log

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, java-native-interface

What is the meaning of logs.(there are lot of similar logs)

```
W/SomeModule: JNI critical lock held for 29.208ms on Thread[22,tid=14865,Runnable,Thread*=0xd5d80800,peer=0x130012b8,"main-some-thread-1"]
```

And how to reverse engineer it to find which is causing it?